# How does light from the Starkiller reach Leia?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, science

OK, the StarKiller base in Episode 7 found a way to send energy from a star millions of light years away at warp speed. Obviously.

However visible light doesn't travel faster than light speed. Right? However, Princess Leia sees other planets destroyed. To do so, she must be standing on the planet looking up at the sky millions of years later, after the light from the StarKiller weapon finally reaches the planet she is on. Luckily, the planet was facing that direction millions of years later. What if she stood there millions of years, but then missed the explosion because the planet was rotated the other way?

Comment: Because of all the fiction.

Comment: Because of red matter.

Comment: Because of stupidity.